# Starting alarm service in android

Tags: android

In my application i want to use alarm service for specific period of time.I'm taking start time and end time values from user and saving it in database,Now i want to start a alarm service at start time and alarm should go off at end time specified by user.I'm new to this topic and not able to understand how to implement this...Any help will be appreciated.Thank u..

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you implement an alarm manager. But you will need to read about Calendar object in android also.

```
 String alarm = Context.ALARM_SERVICE;
 Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

 calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);//Just an example setting the alarm for the 8th hour of a day.
  calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);



AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getActivity().getSystemService(alarm);
//This is the intent that is launched when the alarm goes off.
                    Intent intent = new Intent("WAKE_UP");

PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), 0, intent, 0);



//If the user wants the alarm to repeat then use AlarmManager.setRepeating if they just want it one time use AlarmManager.set().

    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis() , AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, sender);




                    }
```

Also you will need to register a BroadCast Receiver to except the intent when the alarm sets it off. 
You create the BroadCast reciever and register it in your manifest to receive the intent from the alarm.
http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidServices/article.html

Here is a great tutorial to help you understand better

Comment: @coder_For_Life22..thanks for your response...but can u plse tell me how to turn off the alarm service...do i have to check any criteria for that...like pending intent...please help...

Comment: Well when the Alarm Manager fires off a pending intent. It doesnt actually run. What it does is just fires of a Intent such as i have above "WAKE_UP" and in your manifest you register an Broadcast receiver to start when this happens..Then you can have a service or something play music or a ringtone. And when you want it to stop you could use stopService().

Answer (score 0):

The key is to use the [`AlarmManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) with a pending intent.

```
mAlarmSender = PendingIntent.getService(AlarmService.this, 
0, new Intent(AlarmService.this, AlarmService_Service.class), 0);
```

Then you create the AlarmManager from the current context:

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
```

And schedule the previously created pending intent.

```
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                        firstTime, 30*1000, mAlarmSender);
```

On schedule the `AlarmService_Service` service will be called, or you can put another intent like open a specific activity.

Here is the complete example of how you can schedule an alarm: [AlarmService.java](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/AlarmService.html)

Comment: [AlarmManager.cancel(PendingIntent)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#cancel(android.app.PendingIntent)) To cancel pending intents